# Forking Ethereum for an Initial Token Offering

Tags: contract-development, tokens, dapp-development

Ethereum Dev Community,

Please help verify or correct these statements. I am hoping to improve my conceptual knowledge of the Ethereum Blockchain in the following regards, and I hope that the verification or corrections to these statements will help others too.

Regarding starting an initial token offering, my current thinking is that:

1. forking insulates us from happenings on the main ethereum network
   such as excessive CryptoKitty traffic;
2. forking mean that we must start out initially with our own mining;
3. GPU miners that like us will likely seek to mine our token;
4. A forked ethereum token's transaction speed is proportional to its volume of miners.

Again, I am seeking to have these perceptions verified or corrected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forking a blockchain is a huge task.

To fork into a separate blockchain, you have to convince miners, exchanges and waller providers that the new chain is worth putting the extra effort required.

You have to implement protection for a replay attacks, this implies modifying the reference clients and maintaing them.

Answer (score 2):

**Incorrect:** A forked ethereum token's transaction speed is proportional to its volume of miners.

Your network would have the same transaction throughput as the original network unless there is technical innovation involved.